# Let $A$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix and suppose that $A$ is positive definite. Then $a_{jk}\leq$ $\frac 12(a_{jj}+a_{kk})$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix and suppose that A is positive definite. Then

$a_{jk}$ $\leq$ $\frac 12(a_{jj}+a_{kk})$.

Can somebody please explain whether it is True or False? Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a positive definite matrix $A$, you have:
$$
|a_{ij}|^2<a_{ii}a_{jj}.
$$
You can use the fact that all minors of $A$ are positive.
This means that:
$$
|a_{ij}|<\sqrt{a_{ii}a_{jj}}\leq \frac 12(a_{ii}+a_{jj}).
$$

---

Another proof: Take the vector $e_{ij}=[0\, \dots 0\,1\, 0 \dots 0\, \,-1\,\, 0 \dots 0]^T$ with only two non-zero at positions $i$ and $j$. We should have:
$$
e_{ij}^TAe_{ij}>0\implies a_{ii}+a_{jj}-2a_{ij}>0.
$$

Comment: Can you please explain why $|a_{ij}|^2$<$a_{ii}a_{jj}$ ?

Comment: Any submatrix of $A$ is also positive definite and therefore has positive determinant. Apply this to $2\times 2$ submatrix chosen by the intersection of rows and columns $i$ and $j$ whose determinant is simply $a_{ii}a_{jj}-|a_{ij}|^2$.

Comment: @Arash:  second proof very slick, +1!